# Бывает ли подходящий шаблон проектирования для системы работающей на событиях?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Есть система, которая состоит из 2 частей. Части общаются между собой по http. Бизнес процесс состоит из 5 шагов. Часть2 это не мой код, а удаленный сервис. Каждый из шагов запускается в части1 и отпраляет запрос с информацией в часть2. Часть2 выполняет свою задачу по первому шагу и отправляет запрос часть1. Далее процесс продолжается по шагам. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бывают ситуации, когда часть2 при работе ломается и не отправляет запрос, который мы ждем от нее. Вся работа на этом зависает. Нам нужно со стороны части1 следить как долго выполняется работа на части2 и завершать ее со своей стороны если часть2 зависла.

Это был один из примеров проблем в данной модели.

Подскажите, может быть есть какие-то шаблоны проектирования подобных систем? Потому-что подобные системы я писал уже не один раз и думаю, что должна быть информация, полезная для таких вещей.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Ваш яп поддерживает промис?

Comment: @Piterden моя часть системы работает на Go. На go есть горутины.

Comment: Горутина инкапсулирует параллельный процесс, в некоторых случаях создавая новый процесс в os, я же говорю об ожидании (pending) и двух результатирующих состояниях (success и fail)

Comment: @Piterden можно реализовать я думаю. Например взять готовый https://github.com/fanliao/go-promise. Продолжите вашу мысль. Как здесь применить промисы?

Comment: Ждать ответа от удаленного процесса, конечно.